# Empty the autocomplete in Angular on certain event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, autocomplete

I have this Angular Autocomplete i want to clear this input field after `selectFunc()` is called but i don't want to clear `List` model which i have on initial page load, i want to clear the filtered record that user selected.

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
    <input type="text" matInput [ngModel]="List" #searchInput [matAutocomplete]="autocopmlete" (focus)="filter('')" (ngModelChange)="filter($event)">
         <mat-autocomplete  #autocopmlete="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayName">
         <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredObject" [value]="item" (onSelectionChange)="selectFunc($event,item)"> 
            {{ item.Name }} 
         </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
 </mat-form-field>
```

After `selectFunc($event,item)` is called

> Method:

```
 selectFunc(event,userData)
  { 
   if(event.source.selected) {
    
    // Clear Input field at last line of this function 
    
   }
  }
```

> Filter Method :

```
 filter(value = '') {
    if (typeof value !== 'string' || typeof value === 'undefined' || typeof this.List==='undefined') {
        return;
    }
    this.filteredObject = this.List.filter(
        a => ~a.Name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLocaleLowerCase())
    );
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `List = null`?

Comment: @kvetis if i make the List `null` then i'm not getting value the next time i want to filter data, i want to clear selected value after `filter`

Comment: @kvetis Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry, didn't pay attention the first time. Why are you setting `List` as `ngModel` in the first place?

Comment: @kvetis Not an issue, `List` is array type which contains all the records on those records i'm using `filter` function which filters data and only selected data is set in autocomplete which i have to clear after selection not full `List` Array

Comment: Well `ngModel` usually marks the value of the input so I don't think setting is to the list is necessary. If you use some other property like `[ngModel]=search` and deleted the value after selection `search = null` you should get what you're asking here, I think.

Comment: @kvetis Thanks you can post it as answer can you please clear one more doubt that if i have not declared `ngModel` then also `(ngModelChange)="filter($event)"` will be called

Comment: No, I don't think (ngModelChange) would be called without [ngModel]. Maybe you could listen to the native `input` event.

Answer (score 0):

`ngModel` usually marks the value of the input so I don't think setting is to the list (`[ngModel]=list` is necessary. If you use some other property like `[ngModel]=search` and deleted the value after selection `search = null` you should get what you're asking here, I think.

---

Note for readers: `(ngModelChange)` is also called with the selected value, that's the reason OP needs to check whether value is `string` in the `filter` method. Correct typing for the method would be:

```
filter(value: string | ListItem = '')
```

where `ListItem` is the type of options that can be selected in the autocomplete.